# getting user input from a nested function

Tags: powershell

I want to create a nested function that will do some processing and based on that processing it may need user input to continue.  However, when I try running my code, it gets weird output.

```
Set-Variable -Name setme -Option AllScope
$setme = "not set"
$nestedfunction = {
    Write-Output "inside the function `n"
    $setme = Read-Host "Enter Something"
    Write-Output "inside the function setme is: $setme `n"
}

Write-Output "Outisde call: $(&$nestedfunction)"
Write-Output "outside it is $setme"
```

Then when I run it I get:

```
Enter Something: abc
Outisde call: inside the function 
 inside the function setme is: abc 

outside it is not set
```

Regardless of how I nest the function it still ends up like this

```
Set-Variable -Name setme -Option AllScope
$setme = "not set"

$parentfunction = {
    Write-Output "In parent `n"
    $childfunction = {

        Write-Output "inside the function `n"
        $setme = Read-Host "Enter Something"
        Write-Output "inside the function setme is: $setme `n"
    }
    Write-Output "Calling child function `n"
    &$childfunction
}

Write-Output "Outisde call: $(&$parentfunction)"
Write-Output "outside it is $setme"

Enter Something: abc
Outisde call: In parent 
 Calling child function 
 inside the function 
 inside the function setme is: abc 

outside it is not set
```

The end goal is to be able to call a child function, have it process some data, and if the data is invalid, ask the user to re-enter the data.  In my actual script that I want to have this set in, it wont even acknoweldge the Read-Host calls but instead will just bypass them executing everything else.  Does anyone know what I am missing?

Many Thanks~

thank you @Rohin Sidharth that worked :)

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behavior, neither in v2, nor in v5.1, nor in v6.1.0-preview.3. How exactly are you running this code, and what PS version / OS are you on?

Comment: Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
5      1      14393  2312    

on windows server 2016 in powershell ise

Rohin Sidharth actually gave me a good idea that I completely overlooked which was just to use a do while loop which will simplify things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, first off, even though it works essentially like a function, what you have created is a scriptblock. Given your requirements, do something like this.

```
Function Get-UserInput ($message)
{
    $Userinput = Read-Host $message
    Return $Userinput
}

Function Run-ChildFunction ($input)
{
    #Insert processing code here
    if ("data is valid. Insert appropriate variables here")
    {
        Return $true
    }
    else
    {
        Return $false
    }
}

Function Run-ParentFunction
{
    $promptmessage = "Please enter Data"
    Do
    {
        $input = Get-UserInput -message "$promptmessage"
        $ChildReturnvalue = Run-ChildFunction -input $input

        if (!$ChildReturnvalue)
        {
            $promptmessage = "Data is invalid. Please check and re-enter"
        }
    }
    While (!$ChildReturnvalue)
}

Run-ParentFunction
```

Comment: I do not know why I did not just use a do while loop in the first place.  I completely forgot about that since I rarely use them.  I think I was using the scriptblock because I wanted to be able to jump back to it.  I am going to switch it up and just use a do-while loop.  I am still curious as to why the read-host wouldnt work in a script block.  Ill have to continue messing around and see if I can figure that out